# Карта не отображается

Tags: android, yandexmapkit

При открытие карты, она не выводится, просто белый экран в сетку.

В логах  Domain specific configurations require that hostname aware checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[], String, String)

Есть тред https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/issues/80

Но он кажется умер.

Кто-то решал данную проблему, потому что сейчас если используется domain-config, то карта не отображается?

П.С. Ключ добавлен и активен

Comment: В упомянутом треде писали, что вроде вопрос решён. Никто не проверит?